# .sh No such file or directory

Tags: installation, apache-zeppelin

Reference to https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/install/install.html#starting-apache-zeppelin

I have downloaded the package with all interpreters and unpacked under

> /Downloads/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all

I ran

> bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start

and encountered

> bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh: No such file or directory

I think it has something to do with the path setting but I'm not sure what to do. There was no instruction on this in Zeppelin guide.

Comment: are you in the right direcory? if you do `cd /Downloads/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all` and then `ls` what directories you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

The key is the dot slash `./`